# What is the name of JIT compiler used in J2SE platform? How can i find it?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

What is the name of JIT compiler used in J2SE platform? How can i find it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sometimes called the HotSpot(tm) compiler.  The sourcecode is available for download as part of OpenJDK 6 and 7.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the JVM. The Sun JVM contains HotSpot. Other JVMs include IBM, Apache, JRockit.

I dó not believe that others than Sun use codenames externally for their technology

Answer (score 1):

The JIT compiler is simply part of the Java runtime environment, there is not a "standalone" compiler that you can call from external programs, for example.

I believe it's implemented inside of jvm.dll, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

The term 'JIT' became obsolete around 1999. The current HotSpot JVM isn't a JIT in the old sense.